# "Inverting" a concave polygon

Tags: graphics, 2d, trigonometry, vector-graphics

I'm building a 2D game where player can only see things that are not blocked by other objects. Consider this example on how it looks now:

I've implemented raytracing algorithm for this and it seems to work just fine (I've reduced the boundaries for demo to make all edges visible).

[image: Ray tracing example]

As you can see, lighter area is built with a bunch of triangles, each of them having common point in the position of player. Each two neighbours have two common points.

However *I'm willing to calculate bounds for **external** the part of the polygon to fill it with black-colored triangles "hiding" what player cannot see.*

One way to do it is to "mask" the black rectangle with current polygon, but I'm afraid it's very ineffective.

Any ideas about an effective algorithm to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: by _external_ do you mean filling the invisible areas with triangles (or polygons) ?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah Yep, exactly. I've eddited question to clarify that as well.

Answer (score 1):

A non-analytical, rough solution.

- Cast rays with gradually increasing polar angle
- Record when a ray first hits an object (and the point where it hits)
- Keep going until it no longer hits the same object (and record where it previously hits)
- Using the two recorded points, construct a trapezoid that extends to infinity (or wherever)

[image]

Caveats:

- Doesn't work too well with concavities - need to include all points in-between as well. May need Delaunay triangulation etc... messy!
  [image]
- May need extra states to account for objects tucked in behind each other.

[image]